# H3C server requirement

Tags: linux, mysql, ubuntu-18.04, redis-sentinel

I am searching for a server that can best fulfill my requirements. I need it specifically for the best DB I/O performance for a 10-million record database. I am looking for generation-specific details of H3C servers. Please suggest.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.